# .NET Is it possible to share large in-memory collection between processes?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ipc, shared-memory

I have a console application which runs hundred times a day and reads same data from large files (say 50 files with total size of 3-4 Gb).

I am thinking of making a Windows service which will cache the data in memory to speed the access and also control life time of the data (as set of those 50 files may vary from day to day).

I am going to implement shared memory mapped files so the console application will read files from memory written by the service...

However there is another consideration. The data read is converted to .NET objects every time.

So my question - **is there a way to share** not files but **.NET objects (List) in memory?**

*P.S. the data is series of bytes serialised manually*

Comment: See the answer of TomTom. As a workaround, if it suits your requirements, you can create a service which manages the data and executes logic over that data. If its simply searching or aggregating that is..... Your console application would simply invoke a method in the service and deals with the result of that method.

Comment: 3-4 GB in memory? really? Ouch it hurts..

Comment: @Polity - if i could i would not bother with mapped files etc. the logic itself changes 100 times a day. data is static. this is why i am doing things in the way i explained...

Comment: @Steve much more than that. but i am prepared to run subsets (in return i am going to have reduced run time) as i only have 4Gb available for the app.

Comment: 3-4 gb are tiny for some of us. I have .net apps using double digit buffers in memory (10, 15gb). When you track for example prices for financial instruments (say, 200.000) and gets some updates (like 25.000 per second) keeping thigns in memory is the only solution. You write out to disc, but you keep the dcurrent state in memory.

Comment: Note that one of the protocols SQL Server uses is LPC, as in [LPC (Local procedure calls) Part 1 architecture](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2007/07/26/lpc-local-procedure-calls-part-1-architecture/).

Comment: Without falling into the rabbit-hole of writing a full answer, here's how I do it. For .NET, sharing a collection across processes without copying/serialization requires careful overall design from the start. The service will store the in-memory data as contiguous rows of a blittable value-type image (a `struct` that's shared between the client and service) in service-side shared memory. Single rows can then be shared *in-situ* via `IntPtr` communicated via sideband control channel (which itself can be part of the shared memory, thus requiring only a single `IntPtr` communicated per startup).

Comment: To be clear, when I say the control channel can be "part of the shared memory," I'm referring to deploying lock-free techniques, *viz.* `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, etc., over putative well-known locations in a (e.g.) "header" section of the shared memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just implement this as a service that provides a socket-server, and have the console exe just connect to the service and make a request over TCP/IP, getting the response back. Pretty easy to setup, since you already (per the question) have serialization sorted, and very scalable. The service can then keep everything running happily in memory. You can even have the client and server be the same exe - just check `Environment.UserInteractive` when it starts to decide whether to be a client vs a server.

One note: keep the bandwidth low, and avoid a chatty API; meaning: don't have the client do lots of thinking then make 200 requests; just have it package up the entire request and ship it to the server. Let the *server* worry about that all locally, avoiding lots of network traffic.

Comment: Marc. you should read the question better. I already have solution - mapped memory files. I was wondering if there is a way to map objects not files... you socket idea doesnt really help - i will still need to deserialise millions of objects from bytes.. also you know that named pipes are faster than tcp? so what was your point?

Comment: @Bobb yes, you have *a* solution; there are more than one. You were asking about *managed* objects, and no: you can't do that (you'd have to do what you are doing now); however, the thrust of my answer was simply "do it a different way. If your problem doesn't fit, then fine - but I don't have intimate knowledge of your setup, so please don't be snide. Re named pipes; fine; in most similar scenarios I'm looking at, we'd also devote central nodes for that, hence over the network, hence sockets. If all local, then great!

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to share not files but .NET objects (List) in memory?

Being picky - no, no way, allocated object is on a specific process.

You can uise thigns like remoting, but then you basically marshal access between processes.

You can share non-managed space (shared memory), but this can not contain .NET objects - requires marshalling into those.

Comment: Ah - yes and no. The FILES are, but not objects in them. The poster already talked about mem mapped files and the problem is that with a file you have to marshal ack and forth into structs or objects on every read. They do not provide a way to share class instances with gc and all that - and tis is about sharded objects. Shared data space - yes. Different question.

Answer (score 1):

- if you are running this app hundred times per day and you are looking for a way to keep the "data" in memory why don't you keep you the application running instead of close it and restart it again?
- You could create a windows service that load the files in memory and does the elaboration on them. Of course if you stop or restart the service it will need to reload the data
- Another solution would be that instead of keeping in memory objects (which it can be done only using .Remoting or something similar) why don't you import the files into a Data Base which will speed up the process and it can be easily shared between processes?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't directly **share** the collections between multiple .NET processes, but will have to marshal the data across process boundaries. This has a fair amount of CPU overhead, and will consume memory for the objects in both the cache-process and the client.

You could probably achieve something somewhat better with memory mapped files, but that still doesn't allow you to directly map .NET objects on the shared memory - but you say that "the data is series of bytes serialised manually", so it might be a close enough fit?

I don't quite grok the [.NET memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx), the great thing from native code is that you simply treat files as memory pointers, whereas with .NET MMF you need to call accessor methods, and thus do memory copying into .NET objects(?)... but it could probably perform better than reading the files over and over.

Comment: that exactly what i am going to do. read the question: "I am going to implement shared memory mapped files"....